# Set variable value via function in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, typescript2.0

How to tell typescript that a function is responsible for assigning value to a variable?

**EDITED CODE**

The code is simplified. In `getText()` it will never be undefined, but it may be that in another call it will be undefined.

```
class MyClass {

  text: string | undefined = undefined

  setText = (str: string) => {
    this.text = str
  }

  getText = (): string => {

    /* "this.text" will never be undefined */
    if (!this.text) {
      this.setText('TS test')
      //this.text = 'TS test' /* No TS error */
    }

    return this.text // => TS ERROR: Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'
  }
}
```

Comment: The compiler is not able to follow the code's logic and it will be impossible for it to assert such a thing. At least, the `setText` should accept the `text` otherwise you would need a type-guard after the `setText` invocation to let the compiler know that `text` is no longer `undefined`. Does that address your question?

Comment: @wonderflame The javascript code itself does not present any problem, only the typescript shows the error in the editor (vscode). I think about uncommenting the line to omit the error. It will be a redundant code, but it solves the problem. `text = 'TypeScript test' // TS error fix`

Comment: I haven't said that there is an error in javascript. I mean the compiler of typescript. That's the whole point, typescript can't follow your javascript code

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NBQagw) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: If `text` will "never be undefined" then what is the purpose of typing it as `string | undefined` and setting the initial value to `undefined`? Why not just set it to an empty string and drop the `undefined` altogether?

Comment: @jered The code is simplified. In `getText()` it will never be undefined, but it may be that in another call it will be undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Generally it would be bad practice to set variables outside of the scope of the function anyway.

If you want to keep that pattern however, you can use a [type guard](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-type-guards-typescript/) to safely check that `text` is not `undefined` before trying to call a method on it.

```
if (text) {
  text.toUpperCase();
}
```

A conditional statement can inform TypeScript about the type of a variable because the only way the inner code will run is if `text` is not `undefined`.

In general if you stick with this "global variable" pattern with setters, you should go along with TypeScript's effective behavior of treating those variables as if they could be anything in the union type -- because it easily *can* be any of those types.

Comment: There is no error in javascript, as the variable will never be empty. The typescript understands this if I normally assign a value to the variable, but not using the function. [My other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76486226/set-variable-value-via-function-in-typescript/76486266#comment134862080_76486226)

Comment: You're saying that closures which mutate are a bad practice. It really depends on what you're doing. I think it's entirely situational.

Comment: @GilCarvalhoDev I was actually addressing this answer not your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions)

```js
let text: string | undefined

function setText(str: string, variable: any): asserts variable {
  variable = str
}

setText('TypeScript test', text)

text.toUpperCase() // ok
```

However, please keep in mind, that `text` should be a part of function signature

Comment: I don't think this works, can you post an example to TypeScript playground? My understanding is that `asserts` only works within the scope of the function...